# Настройка Nginx на index.php

Tags: php, nginx

Помогите решить проблему, мучаюсь уже часа 2.

В директории `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`

прописал следующее

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html/PayPal/public/index.php;
    index index.php;
    server_name practice www.example.com;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

}

Потом создал ссылку на этот файл командой `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

При переходе `http://practice` - `This site can’t be reached practice’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну так вам нужно настроить домен `practice` и привязать к нему IP-адрес сервера, прежде чем пихать его в nginx

Comment: 1. Ошибка в DNS - он не настроен, и это главное. 2. Ошибка в конфиге, там где `root` должен быть каталог, а смахивает на файл.

Comment: Кроме того, не забывайте, что nginx никогда не занимается запуском php-файлов. Если вы откроете index.php через nginx - вы просто скачаете php-код.

Comment: Я вас понял, как мне можно настроить nginx на index.php ?

Comment: Где нужно прописывать привязку домена и ip?